# Launching NetLogo experiments headless from bash script

Tags: java, netlogo

I am using this line to launch some experiments from bash:

```
java -Xmx50g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp NetLogo.jar org.nlogo.headless.Main --model mymodel.nlogo --setup-file experiments/experiments.xml
```

I am now trying to wrap this into a bash script, but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/sh
MODEL="mymodel.nlogo"
SETUP="experiments/experiments.xml"
java -Xmx50g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp NetLogo.jar org.nlogo.headless.Main --model $MODEL --setup-file $SETUP
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/Users/digitaldust/NetBeansProjects/Jago2/NetLogo.jar!/system/; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 49; Il nome entità deve seguire immediatamente '&' nel riferimento di entità.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:885)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1547)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1319)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader.load(ProtocolLoader.scala:61)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader.loadOne(ProtocolLoader.scala:17)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.newWorker(Lab.scala:27)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.run(Lab.scala:42)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:24)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:197)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Comment: Does that progam work when it is not executed from the jar file (e.g. from within the IDE)? The exception indicates something wrong in the XML, so that it cannot be parsed.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the hint... I have to escape some & in the xml